# can we create array of hashtable in c#.Net?

Tags: arrays, c#-3.0, hashtable

Hashtable itself is a collection but,can we create an array of hashtable?

Comment: Did you try to do this before posting the question? Also, you might want to accept more answers.

Comment: Please remember though: Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*. If you're actually doing this in real software then you're *probably* doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Why not.

```
Hashtable[] hashes = new Hashtable[20];
```

But it is recomended to use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead of Hashtables.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
Hashtable[] arrayOfHashtables = new Hashtable[42];
```